# How to find WSDL interface for a SOAP API? -PowerShell

Tags: powershell, soap

This question is, hopefully, fairly simple.

I have a Web service that I'm querying, `https://myip:8443/AXL`, in this case the application in question is a CUCM server. I know it provides a SOAP API for querying and I'm trying to use `new-webserviceproxy` to connect to it.

Unfortunately WSDL and SOAP are a little opaque to me. I'm relatively confident that the problem is that I'm trying to connect to the wrong uri but at this point I don't know enough to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my command:

`New-WebServiceProxy -Uri https://myip:8443/axl?WSDL -Credential ($AXLCred)`

it returns the following error:

`New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.`

just in case you're concerned my credentials are the problem the following command works fine:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://myip:8443/axl/ -Credential ($AXLCred)`

Comment: First, figure out how to get the WSDL through a browser. "?wsdl" is not a standard, only a convention. It might not work for this service.

Comment: I was looking at that, I'm not sure how to go about tracking that down. Cisco talks about using the AXLAPI,wsdl file they provide with wsdl.exe to creat a custom .NET class for the interface.  I thought that if I could find the URI for wsdl `new-webserviceproxy` should be able to handle that itself.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the comment, I have actually been going through the manuals and am still having a problem, hence the question.  Also your link doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Very odd. Try http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/devguide/6_0_1/cucm_devguide/ccmdvCh1.html. Searching on the page for "WSDL" shows where to get the WSDL from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of WSDL locations.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/devguide/5_0_4/ccmdev/ccmdvCh2.html#wp96739

Comment: Thanks @logicaldiagram, that's exactly what I was looking for! In the end the answer was in the URI I was using.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: That `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet is really handy...  I was not looking forward to making a custom library.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is Cisco UC stuff, which is documented here:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucm/devguide/6_0_1/cucm_devguide/ccmdvCh1.html#wp37665

From the doc, it should be basic auth all the way, which PowerShell should handle without problems. My first stop would be to perform a fiddler or wireshark trace of the two requests and check if authentication headers differ.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll look and see.  So you don't think it's related to the actual URI I'm calling?  I thought it should have wsdl in it somewhere.

Comment: @JasonMorgan: no, the service will not necessarily expose the WSDL. Some services do, and some do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$AXL = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri ($scriptPath + "\AXLAPI.wsdl") -Credential $MyCreds
```

the WSDL file is not available via http you need to catch if from the downloaded AXL toolkit